# Proving the number of solutions to an equation in $p$-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

I'd like to show that the equation $x^3+5x+1=0$ has exactly one solution over $\mathbb{Q}_7$, i.e., the 7-adic numbers.

By Hensel's lemma, one sees that the quation has at least one solution since $1^3+5\cdot1+1\equiv0\mod7$ and $3\cdot1^2+5\not\equiv0\mod7$. But how can I make sure that this one solution is the only solution?

Comment: How does $x^3+5x+5$ factorise modulo $7$? Any solution in $\mathbb Q_7$ must be a solution modulo $7$.

Comment: ... and although distinct solutions in the $7$-adics may be equal mod $7$, this would be reflected in the multiplicity of the corresponding factor of the polynomial reduced mod $7$.

Comment: @Mathmo123: $x^3+5x+5=(x-1)(x^2+x+6)$, so since the latter factor has no solution $\mod 7$, I can conclude that there is no other solution in $\mathbb{Q}_7$?

Comment: No, $x^5+5x+5$ is not $(x-1)(x^2+x+6)$.

Comment: Ok. I forgot to write $\mod 7$

Comment: @bitsbit Yeah that's correct. Note that, as Prof. Garrett pointed out, you do have to use the uniqueness part of Hensel's lemma to be sure that there are no other solutions in $\mathbb Q_7$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $7$

Comment: Oh and of course $x^3 +5x+5$ should be $x^3+5x+1$ in both our comments.

Comment: Alright, thank you all very much!

Comment: And, to add just a bit to the discussion, the fact that $x^2+x+6$ has no root in $\Bbb F_7$ shows that as a $\Bbb Q_7$ polynomial, its roots are to be found in the quadratic unramified extension of $\Bbb Q_7$.